# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 in xcode 8

Tags: sqlite, xcode8, sqlcipher

MY app was working fine with xcode 7. After upgrading to xcode 8 I got 20 symbols not found errors for architecture i386. After including libsqlite3.tdb in the "Link binary with library" section  of build phases, error count reduced but am still left with below errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_key", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteManager openDatabase] in SQLiteManager.o
      -[SQLiteManager reKey] in SQLiteManager.o
  "_sqlite3_rekey", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteManager reKey] in SQLiteManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tried all kinds of architecture changes, etc. How do i get this fixed? 
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Has your application defined `-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC`?

Comment: Yes. Other C Flags has it. I have tried most of the provided solutions but nothing worked..

Answer (score 0):

There were many changes in Xcode 8, and you may need to reconfigure your project to get things working again. There are a detailed set of recommendations for using SQLCipher with Xcode 8 here:

[Important Advisory: SQLCipher with Xcode 8 and new SDKs](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688)